# Silex: error handlers for specific exception types

Tags: exception, silex

It it possible in Silex to use an error handler based on what exception is thrown?

I know this is possible with a single exception handler and a switch statement on the classname of the thrown exception but to me it seems the "Silex way" is cleaner, yet doesn't work.

This is how I would expect it to work

```
<?php
// Handle access denied errors
$app->error(function (\App\Rest\Exception\AccessDenied $e) {
    $message = $e->getMessage() ?: 'Access denied!';
    return new Response($message, 403);
});
// Handle Resource not found errors
$app->error(function (\App\Rest\Exception\ResourceNotFound $e) {
    $message = $e->getMessage() ?: 'Resource not found!';
    return new Response($message, 404);
});
// Handle other exception as 500 errors
$app->error(function (\Exception $e, $code) {
    return new Response($e->getMessage(), $code);
});
```

Problem is that when I throw a ResourceNotFound exception in my controller, the errorhandler tied to AccessDenied is executed

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to {closure}() must be an instance of App\Rest\Exception\AccessDenied, instance of App\Rest\Exception\ResourceNotFound given

Is this achievable in another way or should I just stuff everything in the handler that works with generic Exceptions and switch on the type of exception thrown?

PS: i'm aware of the `$app->abort()` method but prefer working with exceptions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: This feature has now made it into Silex core!

---

This is currently not possible. Right now you'd have to either have a single handler with a switch statement, or many handlers with an `if ($e instanceof MyException)` each.

I do like the idea though, and it should be possible to implement it by using reflection. It would be awesome if you could create a new ticket [on the tracker](https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/issues), or even work on a patch, if you're interested.

Cheers!

Comment: Hey Igor, thanks a lot, I've actually just put a proposal on the mailinglist, can you please check it and give some feedback, then I'll finish it and send in a pull request.

Comment: I've updated my answer, as this feature is now available in silex core. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that I use in my projects:

```php
class ProcessCallbackException extends Exception
{
    public function __construct(\Closure $callback, $message = "", Exception $previous = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, 0, $previous);
        $this->callback = $callback;
    }

    public $callback;
}

class AccessDeniedException extends ProcessCallbackException
{
    public function __construct($message = null)
    {
        $f = function() {
            return app()->redirect('/login');
        };

        parent::__construct($f, $message);
    }
}

# Handle your special errors
$app->error(function (\Exception $e, $code) {
    if ($e instanceof ProcessCallbackException)
    {
        /** @var ProcessCallbackException $callbackException */
        $callbackException = $e;
        return call_user_func($callbackException->callback);
    }
    else
        return null;
});
```